# Dynamically change select options based on parent selection

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I'm not even sure it this is possible in WordPress, but...

I can get all the categories like this...

```
<select name="category" id="category" required>
    <option></option>
    <?php 
    $categories = get_categories('hide_empty=0&order=ASC&orderby=name');
    foreach ($categories as $cat) :
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $cat->cat_ID;?>"><?php echo $cat->cat_name;?></option>
        <?php

    endforeach;
?>
```

...which outputs something like this...

```
<select name="category" id="category" required>
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">Shoes</option>
    <option value="2">Pants</option>
    <option value="3">Shirts</option>
</select>
```

But what I'd also like to do is have a secondary selection that populates the options automatically based on the choice made in the first selection field.

For example, if I selected 'Pants' from the first selection, then the secondary selection would automatically show all the available posts from the 'pants' category, for example:

```
<select name="category_posts" id="category_posts">
    <option value="13">Long</option>
    <option value="14">Short</option>
    <option value="15">Evening</option>
    <option value="16">Hot</option>
    <option value="17">Sports</option>
</select>
```

As mentioned those posts are from the 'pants' category.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: You need to apply ajax to get dynamic `posts` from server.

Comment: As @Rishi said you can need ajax for that, or you can preload all posts then use javascript to hide irrelative options.